# How to stop and resume loops in c# in console application

Tags: c#, for-loop, console-application

How to stop the loop by clicking e.g. the `P` key and return to the beginning of the loop by pressing the `Enter` key?

I don't know where I'm making a mistake - I'm asking for help and the code of my application is below. I used the `P` and `Enter` key binding and Timer Elapsed.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Timers;

namespace pauza
{
    internal class Program
    {
        //static int iTimer = 0;
        static Timer timer = new Timer(10000);
        
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string @obinumer00;
            string @obinumer01;

            SqlConnection conn00 = new SqlConnection("Data Source=XXX.XX.XX.X;Initial Catalog=DEMO;User ID=sa;Password=demo1234;MultipleActiveResultSets=true");
            string sql00 = "SELECT [GidWZ] FROM [DEMO].[dbo].[WWZ]";
            SqlCommand cmd00 = new SqlCommand(sql00, conn00);
            conn00.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter adapter00 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd00);
            DataTable dt00 = new DataTable();
            adapter00.Fill(dt00);
            while (dt00.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                try
                {

                    SqlConnection conn01 = new SqlConnection("Data Source=XXX.XX.XX.X;Initial Catalog=DEMO;User ID=sa;Password=demo1234;MultipleActiveResultSets=true");
                    string sql01 = "SELECT top 1 [GidWZ], [CodePost] FROM [DEMO].[dbo].[WWZ]";
                    SqlCommand cmd01 = new SqlCommand(sql01, conn01);
                    conn01.Open();
                    SqlDataReader reader01 = cmd01.ExecuteReader();
                    if (reader01.Read())
                    {
                        @obinumer00 = reader01.GetValue(0).ToString();
                        @obinumer01 = reader01.GetValue(1).ToString();

                        timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;
                        timer.Start();
                        //use Console Key Class to read a key from keyboard    
                        ConsoleKeyInfo cki = new ConsoleKeyInfo();
                        cki = Console.ReadKey(true);

                        //I am using letter 'p' to pause    
                        if (cki.Key == ConsoleKey.P)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Process Is Paused,Press 'Enter' to Continue...");
                            timer.Stop();
                        }
                        ConsoleKeyInfo ckm = new ConsoleKeyInfo();
                        ckm = Console.ReadKey(true);

                        //I am using letter 'p' to pause 
                        if (ckm.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Resuming Process...");
                        }

                        //other code
                    }
                    conn01.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (cdn_api.Logout(SessionID) != 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("No data to process");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Sesion closed");
                    }
                }
                continue;
            }
            conn00.Close();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You'd probably want to put the loop into a separate thread and keep watching for input on the main thread. That is if I understood the objective correctly.

Comment: Furthermore, `Console.ReadKey()` will wait till you enter a key ...

Comment: "Depending on your application, you might want to use the ReadKey method in conjunction with the KeyAvailable property"

Answer (score 0):

It demonstrates what you need:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Timers;
namespace pauza {
    internal class Program {
        static System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;
            timer.AutoReset = true;
            timer.Start();
            Thread.Sleep(20000);
        }
        private static void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e) {
            if (Console.KeyAvailable)
                switch (Console.ReadKey(true).Key) {
                    case ConsoleKey.P: 
                        Console.WriteLine("Process Is Paused,Press 'Enter' to Continue...");
                        break;
                    case ConsoleKey.Enter: 
                        Console.WriteLine("Resuming Process...");
                        break;
                }
        }
    }
}
```

If you process your data one by one, you should not involve a timer. Just check and process 'Console.KeyAvailable' every data processing cycle.

Answer (score 0):

As Fildo said in the comments you should put your loop in a separate thread. I provided you with a sample code here but you can extend it based on your business.

```
ManualResetEvent resetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(true);
Thread loopThread = new Thread(Looper);
loopThread.Start();

while (true)
{
    var keyPressed = Console.ReadKey(true);

    if (keyPressed.Key == ConsoleKey.P)
    {
        resetEvent.Reset();
        Thread.Sleep(1000); 
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Process Is Paused,Press 'Enter' to Continue...");
    }

    if (keyPressed.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
    {
        resetEvent.Set();
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Resuming Process ...");
    }

    if (keyPressed.Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
    {
        resetEvent.Reset();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Process's ended...");
        loopThread.Interrupt();
        break;
    }

}

Thread.Sleep(1000);
Console.WriteLine("press any key for exit...");
Console.ReadLine();

void Looper()
{
    try
    {
        while (true)
        {
            resetEvent.WaitOne();
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Console.Write(@" . ");
        }
    }
    catch (ThreadInterruptedException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("thread interrupted.");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to stop the loop...");

        // Your loop logic here
        while (true)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("loop running ...");
            // Check if a key is available without blocking
            if (Console.KeyAvailable)
            {
                // Read the key to clear the input buffer
                Console.ReadKey(true);
                break; // Break out of the loop
            }

            // Your loop body here
            // ...
            // For example, sleep for a short duration
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Loop stopped!");
    }
}
```